# Is there a correct way to set up a Stargate?

Tags: stargate

Is there a correct way to set up a Stargate, i.e. one side that is top and one that is down? If so, is it marked in any way? If so, what would happen if it were set up the wrong way around?

If not, how does the Stargate know which direction is down?

Picture of the Stargate on Earth:
[image: Example of a Stargate]

Comment: @mwarren There is nothing different about the top that I can see: https://www.filmfutter.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/StargateSerie-696x385.jpg

Comment: There is certainly a "front" and "back" but I don't think there is an "up" and "down"

Comment: The first part seems easy to answer. The gates themselves probably do not require specific alignment because they also work in space where alignment is irrelevant. As far as markings go, the only ones shown and explained are the symbols/chevrons and those are on the front, i.e. the enter/exit side of the event horizon. But regarding the second part, I couldn't find an answer even after doing some research. I'm not sure this was ever answered. I don't think that retaining direction and speed through the gate covers this. Doesn't explain why you can't end up upside down and fall on your head.

Comment: There might be some sort of gravity sensor in the gate to allow it to detect which way is down

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the original *Stargate* film, the top chevron was designed to be visibly different from the others ([wider and with a different pattern](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a2/b0/72/a2b0723043a979c92f62015070512036.jpg)) and presumably would serve as a "***this way up***" indicator.

[image: Close-up of the top of the stargate from the movie Stargate, showing the top three chevrons. The topmost chevron has two planes on either side of the triangular indicator, the inner one patterned with horizontal stripes and the outer one flat with raised edge. The chevrons on either side lack the outermost plane.]

In the TV series, there doesn't appear to be anything that would immediately identify (visually) the top and the bottom, but when you dial, **the top chevron activates *each time*** whereas the side chevrons ***only activate in sequence***, so that would serve as an easy indicator of which way to place the gate. Just start dialling, see which one activates twice in a row and you've got your top.

It's also worth pointing out that the Atlantis team enter 'space gates' from any which angle in their Puddle Jumpers but *always come out right-side-up* in the Atlantis Gate Room, so the gate system is clearly taking into account that the gate itself might not be completely upright when entered, compared to the local equivalent of 'down' (and responding accordingly).

It follows that there may not even be any need for the gate to be placed in any particular orientation, other than for convenience and aesthetics.

Comment: Note also that unless there's a chevron at the bottom that gets skipped in the normal dialing sequence, there's a gap between the 3rd and 4th chevrons that makes the overall layout non-uniform, so we might assume that the bit with no chevrons is "down."

Comment: @DavidW - Plus if you look at the prop, that's where the lighting loom and all the wires for the spinny motor go :-)

Comment: Hmm. Not sure it's worthy of mention, but on some of the concept art, some gates have fewer chevrons (seven, not nine) and the gate doesn't have vertical symmetry; https://i.pinimg.com/originals/f9/97/1d/f9971dfad68166a7547e27fb849857c0.jpg

Comment: I'd like to point out that your answer in regarding the design is only true for the movie and/or the 2nd generation Milkyway gates. The Destiny-style 1st generation and Pegasus-style 3rd generation gates had a totally different visual style. The Destiny-style gates have something like the chevrons but they just glow while the gate is dialing/active. None of them 'activate'. Also none of them are marked or distinct from the others. Destiny itself has a "light bulb" above the gate that could mark the "up" direction but that was missing from the seeded gates on the planets.

Comment: @Sebastian_H - The Destiny stargate was installed by the Alterans, so presumably the appropriate 'way up' would have been obvious to someone who can actually build gates. The same is also true of the [supergate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NjfhWxZ0xUI), which activates subjectively from top to bottom and which Sam somehow knows to approach at the correct plane.

Comment: Make your planets gate able to be rotated 180 degrees so any invaders drop on their heads from 20 feet up, cheap iris

Comment: @Celestialgranturismo - The problem with booby traps is remembering that you set them fifty years later.

Comment: Amazing they didn’t incorporate *some* type of MALP into the stargates from the ground up: at least some telemetry back to the DHD like gate orientation, atmosphere, temperature. Whether it’s buried in rock or ice or some species decided to lay it down flat and use it as a garbage disposal of the gods. Smartest race in the galaxy though.. guess nobody hit a titanium plate 3microns off the event horizon in the simulations

Comment: @DavidW the stargates we see in the SG-1 continuity have 9 chevrons - 7 are used in day-to-day ops, an eighth is used when they meet the Asgard for the first time (referred to as long distance dialling) and I think the ninth is used for the SG Universe pilot (been a while since I saw that, might be wrong).

Comment: @Celestialgranturismo - There's hundreds of inputs that Sam has bypassed to get the gate to work. Who knows what additional functionality was originally there that isn't being used.

Comment: They dial home ‘normally’ from DHDs all the time and have no idea if the iris is open or the planet has air or the gate is underwater or in space. Even on Atlantis, this functionality doesn’t seem to exist. And the Ancients clearly engineered it radio waves could pass both ways: but instead of a clear picture from photons passing back and forth, you get wavy blue water. In fairness, the gate was designed by them, for them: they didn’t expect the monkeys to evolve and start playing around with them millennia later..